# Getting strange output on commands that used to work

Tags: data, dataset

I have used the following code before and it worked then but now it seems to default to the word `Function`, and some of the other commands are giving results like `All` when they used to work.

Would you help clarify what's going on?

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "USStates"][
  All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"]} &]
usaStateCases[s_] := 
       Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
          All, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First
        
usaStateDeaths[s_] := 
       Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
          All, #Deaths["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First
        
usaStateCases["California"]
```

This used to work but now, the output of the last line is `Function`.

Comment: We cannot test your code because you did not provide the contents of `data`. Can you give a source or an example?

Comment: Thank you.  Please note my edit.  TIA.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that the OP $data$ ever worked for 2 reasons.  First, in the definition $data$, the "LastValue" property of a TimeSeries object is called returning an `Integer` in the second column. `Integer` has no "LastValue" property that is subsequently called in the $usaStateXXX$ functions.

```
data[[1, 2]] // Normal // Head
(* Integer *)
```

Second, the definition of $data$ is not transforming columns, rather it is returning a new list of lists of functions applied to columns.  This can be seen in the documentation for [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) under the details section shown here.

[image: Dataset Details]

Inspection of $data$, shows that it is a list of lists with no column names.

```
data
```

[image: data Dataset displayed]

If it is desired for the $usaStateXXX$ functions to work, just build $data$ by providing the column keys as shown:

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "USStates"][All, {"AdministrativeDivision", "ConfirmedCases"}]
```

## Extended Response to flinty's Comment

I am a `Dataset` novice versus a `Dataset` jock.  My main motivation to answering MSE questions is to build MMA skills in areas that I am deficient, so any help is welcome.

In this case, let's look at a [simple dataset](https://wolfram.com/xid/0rs3seh0m-5dy4of) from the documentation.

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

Now, let's examine three ways to operate on the dataset and see what it returns.

### 1. Take Specific Columns of the Dataset Using Keys

If we want to take specific columns of the dataset using keys, then it will return a list of associations as can be seen by the dataset formatting or the `Normal` representation.

```
dataset[All, {"a", "b"}]
dataset[All, {"a", "b"}] // Normal
```

[image: Keys image]

### 2.  Apply a List of Functions to All Rows (OP Case)

If we apply a list of anonymous functions to the dataset, then it will return a list of lists.  As such, it lost its column headings so that it cannot be used in subsequent operations.  This is similar to how $data$ was constructed in the OP.

```
dataset[All, {#a, #b} &]
dataset[All, {#a, #b} &] // Normal
```

[image: Applying list of functions]

I would say that this is "unlikely" to be a new behavior in dataset, but I am novice.

### 3.  Apply Functions to Columns Returning Dataset with Column Names

To apply functions to columns and retain or create new column headings, we need to use associations as shown in the [Dataset Documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0rs3seh0m-xs1z34).

```
dataset[All, <|"a'" -> #a, "b'" -> #b|> &]
dataset[All, <|"a'" -> #a, "b'" -> #b|> &] // Normal
```

[image: Functions with Column Names in Dataset]

### Conclusion

Independent of whether there has been a change in the `ResourceFunction`, operating on the data like case 2 will return a dataset without column headers (at least for my version `12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)`).  The subsequent functions rely on those column headers.  Therefore, I considered it "unlikely" that it worked.  Someone would have to look at another version to see if the operation returned a list of associations, but then one would have to contend with the `Integer` type not having a "LastValue" property as in the `TimeSeries` object.

Comment: Tim, I can only see a difference in the `data` statement. If that’s right, then perhaps you should remove the rest of the code that is identical. It would also be helpful if you could explain your change.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried to incorporate your comments.  Sometimes I get requests to include the entire workflow, but you are probably correct.  I guess I was in a rush to sneak an answer before bedtime.

Comment: thank you for the edits. It makes a lot more sense to me now. (+1)

Comment: _It is unlikely that the OP data ever worked for 2 reasons_ No it really *did* work at one point because I provided this code and got good numbers - I think what's happened is the data has changed layout after a resource update from wolfram, but you'll just have to take my word on that because I can't get back to the original data and now I'm seeing the errors OP gets.

Comment: @flinty I added an extended response to your comment at the end of the answer.  Using a simple test dataset from the Basic Examples section of `Dataset` shows that the OP construction should return a list of lists versus a list of associations (needed to refer to column headers) that would be required for the subsequent functions to work.  So, it does not require the `ResourceFunction` to change only that the behavior of `Dataset` has changed.  That is why I considered it "unlikely".

Comment: My experience with Dataset is that it has a lot of heuristics built-in. Sometimes adding one more row or one more column to a dataset changes the Dataset behavior and classification of the data completely. That seems to happen more with smaller numbers of rows and/or columns. So you are trying to building up to a real problem from a toy problem and it gets very confusing. I've done better by starting with slightly larger toy problems. Also since the internal behavior is not documented or promised, changes seem to be made with new versions of Mathematica.

Comment: @PaulCommentary I don't necessarily disagree, but in this case both the toy problem and the actual full scale problem currently return the behaviors that I documented in the answer.  Also, the "Show Changes" button in the `Dataset` documentation do not highlight any changes in the Basic Examples section from where I drew the examples.